# returning an array of images retrieved from a url with jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Im getting a null pointer exception when I attempt to get an array of image urls using jsoup, really not sure what Im doing wrong here as I appears that Im following the example layed out in the javadoc, any help would go a long way thanks.

```
public class ImagetestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String url = "http://www.goal.com/en/news/1717/editorial/2012/05/20/3116140/in-pictures-chelsea-celebrate-champions-league-success#";
    Document doc = null;
    List<Element> media = new ArrayList<Element>();
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    media = doc.select("[src]");

    for (Element src : media) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("img")) {
            Toast.makeText(ImagetestActivity.this, src.text(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: printing a stack trace and rolling over that IOException is probably not a good way to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
media = doc.select("img[src]");

for (Element src : media) {
   Toast.makeText(ImagetestActivity.this, src.attr("src"),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I.e. select images (no need to check the tag name). And probably you need src attribute value, not inner text (which is always empty)

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work either, very strange why this isnt working tbh

Comment: can you print your NPE stacktrace?

Comment: OMG! I forgot to add in the internet permission because this was merely going to be a test project, had to be something totally stupid! lolololol